# Composer Ignores composer.json of a Specific Commit

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to use a very specific commit from the repository:

`"monolog/monolog": "dev-master#7d20351afc85aa23c5795309c9984a1e93d81c27"`

What happens is that I get the following error message:

```
Problem 1
    - monolog/monolog dev-master requires php ^7.1 -> your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
    - monolog/monolog dev-master requires php ^7.1 -> your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for monolog/monolog dev-master#7d20351afc85aa23c5795309c9984a1e93d81c27 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[dev-master].
```

Which would be reasonable if I was pointing to just master since its `composer.json` does require ^7.1 of php. However, the [specific](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/7d20351afc85aa23c5795309c9984a1e93d81c27/composer.json) version that I need does not. I assume it checks master instead of whatever I give it. How can I go around this problem?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug you should post in their issue tracker.

Comment: Created an issue here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7438. Meanwhile, if anyone knows how to fix this, it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and documented:

> While this is convenient at times, it should not be how you use packages in the long term because it comes with a technical limitation. **The composer.json metadata will still be read from the branch name you specify before the hash.** Because of that in some cases it will not be a practical workaround, and you should always try to switch to tagged releases as soon as you can.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#i-have-locked-a-dependency-to-a-specific-commit-but-get-unexpected-results-

In your case you should probably be able to use different branch name as a workaround:

```
"monolog/monolog": "1.x-dev#7d20351afc85aa23c5795309c9984a1e93d81c27"
```

But the best solution will be to switch to regular constraints and use tagged releases. This hash refers to 3 years old version, you should probably upgrade to something newer.

Comment: I see now. Yeah, old codebase and php version that is behind makes it hard. The project is 9 years old. I'd gladly use tagged releases otherwise.